# Jenkins: Copying views and adding jobs to view

Tags: python, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to figure out how can I differentiate jenkins builds between users. My main use case is a user wanting to build and run our test jobs his SVN branch.

Since I have many users, I want these jobs to have a "label" of some sort to identify the user and branch, and prevent collision between jobs, because if they have the same name they will use the same workspace directory which will delete other users jobs.

The only way I could find was to programatically copy the jobs and change their properties (name and branch for example).

So if you want to keep my jobs in order, I wanted to be able organize the users jobs in views and I'm using the nested view plugin, but all the Jenkins APIs only show creating a simple view, and I want use the nested view. So what I thought was to copy a "template view" and change its properties.

Is there a way to do this through the REST API or python (preferable)?

Thanks!

Comment: A comment on "The only way I could find was to programatically copy the jobs and change their properties" -- the [svnmerge plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Merge+Plugin) might make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) in order to transparently provide a user-specific variable to be used later. This plugin provides several variables:

[image]

[Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) can be used to define a job with all required configuration regarding the actual build process. Having that, you can create several "wrapper" jobs, following %UserName-JobName% pattern, so it will be quite an easy task to have different views, configured to show jobs only for a certain user. Wrapper jobs are supposed only to execute upper layer template job (use upper layer builders).

[image]

Please also consider [Hudson Personal View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hudson+Personal+View).

Answer (score 0):

Create a parametrized build that takes in a SVN path as a parameter. In the SVN configuration set the URL to $. To keep the workspaces from being cleared, configure the project to archive the build after each run. If you want your users to be able to run builds concurrently Jenkins will create multiple workspaces and keep things separate. You can use the [Build Name Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) to tag each build with the SVN path or with another parameter.